# The natural parameterization of the exponential class of densities always exist?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, exponential-distribution

**Def.** ***Exponential Class of Densities***

The density function $f\left ( \mathbf{x};\mathbf{\Theta} \right )$ is a member of the exponential class of density functions iff
$$f\left ( \mathbf{x};\mathbf{\Theta} \right )=\begin{cases}
 \exp\left [ \sum_{i=1}^{k}c_{i}(\mathbf{\Theta})g_{i}(\mathbf{x})+d(\mathbf{\Theta})+z(\mathbf{x})) \right ]& \text{for}\quad \mathbf{x}\in A,\\
 0& \text{ otherwise } , 
\end{cases}
$$
where $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_n)^{'},\mathbf{\Theta}=(\theta_1,...,\theta_k)^{'};c_{i}(\mathbf{\Theta}),i=1,...,k,$ and $d(\mathbf{\Theta})$ are real-valued functions of $\mathbf{\Theta}$ that do not depend on $\mathbf{x};g_i(\mathbf{x}),i=1,...,k,$and $z(\mathbf{x})$ are real-valued functions of $\mathbf{x}$ that do not depend on  $\mathbf{\Theta};$ and $A\subset\mathbf{R}^{n}$ is a set of $n$-tuples contained in $n$-dimensional real space whose definition dose not depend on the parameter vector $\mathbf{\Theta}.$

---

Considering an alternative parameterization of the exponential class of densities

$$f_{*}\left ( \mathbf{x};\mathbf{c} \right )=\exp\left [ \sum_{i=1}^{k}c_{i}g_{i}(\mathbf{x})+d_{*}(\mathbf{c})+z(\mathbf{x})) \right ]I_{A}(\mathbf{x}),\mathbf{c}=(c_1,...,c_k)\in \Omega_{\mathbf{c}},$$  with $$d_{*}(\mathbf{c})=\log\left [ \int_{\mathbf{R}^n}\exp\left\{  \sum_{i=1}^{k}c_{i}g_{i}(\mathbf{x})+z(\mathbf{x})) \right\}I_{A}(\mathbf{x})\mathrm{d}{\mathbf{x}}\right ]^{-1}$$
(use summation in the discrete case). This parameterization is
referred to as ***the natural parameterization of the exponential class of densities***. Note that the definition of $d_{*}(\mathbf{c})$ is a direct result of
the fact that the density must integrate (or sum) to $1$.

---

The natural parameterization of an exponential class of densities maybe not unique.
I have a very elementary problem:Is there such an exponential class of densities its natural parameterization does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

$[\rm I]$ defines the exponential family with the densities of the form $$ \exp\{A(x)B(\theta)+C(x)+D(\theta)\};\tag 1\label 1$$ $\eqref 1$ is natural exponential family if $A(\cdot) $ is linear.

Consider $X$ following lognormal distribution. Then one can show $A(x) =\ln x$ and thus a lognormal family is not natural exponential family.

---

### Reference:

$\rm [I]$ Unifying the Named Natural Exponential Families and Their Relatives, *Carl N. Morris, Kari F. Lock,* The American Statistician, August $2009,$ DOI: 10.1198/tast.2009.08145.

---

---

Canonical forms are the building (cf.$\rm [I]$) blocks of exponential family of distributions. Formally, with a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R^n,$ a non-negative real valued function $h:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R, $ a set of $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak B}(\mathbb R^n) /\boldsymbol{\mathfrak B}(\mathbb R) $ measurable functions $\langle T_i\rangle_{1\leq i\leq s},$ for $\boldsymbol\eta\in\mathbb R^s,$ let $$ \Xi:=\{\boldsymbol\eta:A(\boldsymbol\eta)<\infty\}$$ where $$ A(\boldsymbol\eta) =\ln\int \exp\left[\boldsymbol\eta^\top\mathbf T\right]h(\mathbf x) ~\mathrm d\mu.$$ Then the density $$p(\mathbf x;\boldsymbol\eta)=\exp\left[\boldsymbol\eta^\top\mathbf T-A(\boldsymbol\eta)\right]h(\mathbf x) \tag 1$$ is an $s$-parameter exponential family in canonical form (cf. $\rm [II]$).

$\Xi$ is the maximal parameter (cf.$\rm [III]$) space.

One can make other parameterizations of the density by taking a mapping of the form $\boldsymbol\theta\mapsto \boldsymbol \eta(\boldsymbol\theta) $ from some space $\Omega$ to $\Xi$ to get $$p(\mathbf x;\boldsymbol\theta)=\exp\left[\boldsymbol\eta(\boldsymbol\theta)^\top\mathbf T-B(\boldsymbol\theta)\right]h(\mathbf x) \tag 2$$ where $B(\boldsymbol\theta) := A(\boldsymbol\eta(\boldsymbol\theta)). $ Family $\{p(~;\boldsymbol\theta):\boldsymbol\theta\in\Omega\}$ is an $s$-paramter-exponential family.

$\rm [IV]$ formalizes the process of building up an exponential family (for simplicity, we will be dealing with families with parameter one):

$\bullet$ Start with a density $h$ w.r.t.  the $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu.$

$\bullet$ By exponential tilting, construct a family of densities proportional to $\exp(\eta x)h(x);$ consider  $M(\eta) = \int_\mathcal X e^{\eta x}h(x)~\mathrm d\mu;$ if $M(\eta)$ is finite for $\theta$ in a nhood of $0,$  it is the mgf of $h(x).$ Take $\Xi:= \{\theta\in \mathbb R: M(\theta)<\infty\}.$ If $\Xi$ is not degenerate, construct the family $\mathcal F_{ne}^1$ by $\eta \mapsto \exp\{\eta x- A(\eta)\}h(x),$ where $A(\eta)$ is the cumulant generating function of the distribution with pdf $h(x).$

$\bullet$ Let $T(x)$ be a statistic with cgf $A_T(\eta), ~\eta\in \Xi_T\subset\Xi.$ Then $\exp\{\eta T(x)-A_T(\eta)\}h(x)$ is a density for $\eta\in \Xi_T.$

$\bullet$ Consider a mapping $\Phi\to \Xi_T:\phi\mapsto\eta(\phi).$ Then the class of densities $$\exp\{\eta(\phi)T(x)- A_T(\eta(\phi))\}h(x) \equiv \exp\{\eta(\phi)T(x)- B(\phi)\}h(x)$$ is (full if $\eta(\Phi) = \Xi$) exponential family, denoted by $\mathcal F_e^1.$

$\bullet$ For each $\mathcal F_{ne}^1,$ there is an associated $\mathcal F_e^1$ induced by $T(\cdot)$ and parameterized by $\eta = \eta(\phi),$ that is $\exp\{\eta t- B(\phi(\eta))\}h_T(t)$ where $\eta(\phi)$ is assumed to be one-to-one with inverse $\phi(\theta).$

In a nutshell, as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family) states

> By defining a transformed parameter $\eta = \eta(\theta)$, it is always possible to convert an exponential family to canonical form.

---

### References:

$\rm [I]$ Mathematical Statistics: Basic Ideas and Selected Topics- Vol. $\mathsf I, $ *Peter J. Bickel, Kjell A. Doksum,* Taylor & Francis, $2015, $ sec. $1.6.3, $ p. $56.$

$\rm [II]$ Theoretical Statistics: Topics for a Core Course, *Robert W. Keener,* Springer Science$+$Business, $2010, $ sec. $2.1, $ pp. $25-26.$

$\rm [III]$ Theory of Statistical Inference, *Anthony Almudevar,* Taylor & Francis, $2022, $ sec. $3.6, $ p. $73.$

$\rm [IV]$ Principles of Statistical Inference: From a Neo-Fisherian Perspective, *Luigi Pace, Alessandria Salvan,* World Scientific, $1997,$ sec. $5.2,$ pp. $172, 175-176.$

Comment: It seems that your counterexample is about **natural exponential family** while OP is interested in **natural reparametrization** -- the former one is more stringent.

Comment: @Zhanxiong thanks for vigil observation. I missed that. I have added substantial element to the post.

Comment: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Parametric_Statistical_Inference/YnsQ-NnMxJ8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=xponential%20family%20are%20not%20always%20,%20or%20even%20often%20,%20written%20in&pg=PA28&printsec=frontcover  said that "Obviously,members of the exponetial family are not always,or even often,written in terms of the parameter $\theta$,when they are,it is called the natural or canonical parametrization of the family...... "

Comment: @Elisa, what does the statement indicate? Does it in anyway negate the existence of a canonical form? On a particular note, the author uses $\boldsymbol \theta$ in place of $\boldsymbol\eta.$

Comment: From that statement, it seems the exponetial families may not always have  the cannonical form.I am not sure which one is right.

Comment: The author didn't mean that in any way. As I wrote in the post, canonical form is the simplest representation which can be reparameterized to other form. The author of your source corroborated that in that statement. Canonical forms always exist.